# PHPMailer: Check if Error is an Auth Error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using `PHPMailer` to send some mails by a SMTP Server. `$mail->send()` will return false on an error and `$mail->ErrorInfo` holds some text about the error.

That is fine. But how is it possible to check programmatically if the error was due to an invalid auth?

Comment: AFAIK PHPMailer will throw an exception if the authentication failed (at least for SMTP). You can catch the exception and check the error message. Just as an idea.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't especially easy in PHPMailer at present, and will rely on string matching to a large extent. This is why [this issue](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/1579) is currently open, if you'd care to contribute to that.

If you enable exceptions (by passing `true` to the constructor) you can get slightly better info than the `ErrorInfo` property provides, but it's not a vast improvement.